# Reduce results based on previous record + LINQ + SQL

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to figure out how to do this with either LINQ or SQL.

I have a table called Activity, a process continously logs to it every day. This process checks for a certain condition (Found or Not). My table data looks like:

| Date | Found |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 0 |
| 1/2/2021 | 0 |
| 1/3/2021 | 1 |
| 1/4/2021 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 | 0 |
| 1/6/2021 | 0 |
| 1/7/2021 | 0 |
| 1/8/2021 | 0 |
| 1/9/2021 | 0 |

I would like to reduce this result to show when a transition has occurred and the previous record (previous day):

| Date | Found |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/2021 | 0 |
| 1/3/2021 | 1 |
| 1/5/2021 | 0 |

The only solution I can think of is to do a loop in C# and check for the changes and record them in a new collection. But I would really like to know if something like this is possible with SQL or LINQ.

Comment: What LINQ would you be using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? If using a database, what database provider?

Comment: What if 1/5 was a 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want rows where the row, the previous row, or the next row has `found = 1`.  One method uses `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(found) over (order by date) as prev_found,
             lead(found) over (order by date) as next_found
      from t
     ) t
where 1 in (prev_found, found, next_found);
```

You can also use a window frame:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(found) over (order by date rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as num_found
      from t
     ) t
where num_found > 0;
```

Comment: Wow thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Had no idea about the lag and lead functions.